# Getting a Node from a work point in space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to get a Node form a position in a world space. the nodes are arranged in a grid fashion

Below is an image of how the grids of nodes are each large grid numbered 0 - 3 
are made up from a 50 x 50 grid of nodes.

the red dots within each of the grid represents which nodes was checked when a point in the world was clicked.

for the large grid labeled 0 each node is access correctly

Grid 1 has the correct X values (left to right position) but the Z is clamped at the top of the grid

Grid 2 has the opposite where the X values are clamped to the top range and the Z values are correct

Grid 3 both X and Z are clamped to the max value. 
[image: Grid]

Below is the code for grid from the world position

```
    public Node NodeFromWorldPoint(Vector3 worldPosition)
{

    //Gets the Large grid number 0-3
    float Largex = worldPosition.x / (4 * gridWorldSize.x);
    float LargeZ = worldPosition.z / (4 * gridWorldSize.z);
    Largex = Mathf.Clamp01(Largex);
    LargeZ = Mathf.Clamp01(LargeZ);
    int lx = Mathf.RoundToInt((2 - 1) * Largex);
    int lz = Mathf.RoundToInt((2 - 1) * LargeZ);

    int tilenumber = lx * 2 + lz;

    //get the position of the smaller grid
    float percentX = worldPosition.x / (gridWorldSize.x * 2 );
    float percentZ = worldPosition.z / (gridWorldSize.z * 2);
    percentX = Mathf.Clamp01(percentX);
    percentZ = Mathf.Clamp01(percentZ);
    int x = Mathf.RoundToInt((gridSizeX - 1 ) * percentX);
    int z = Mathf.RoundToInt((gridSizeZ - 1) * percentZ);
    var gc = grids.ElementAt(tilenumber);
    return gc[x, z];
}
```

Comment: Do u want to get the node that is clicked? or a node under the cursor? or a just a node at specific point in world space?

Comment: Please post full script for better understanding

Comment: u can use OnClickEvent, RayCast, or Physics.OverlapSphere depending on ur requirement

Comment: @HassaanAkbar node as a specific point in world space, the world position vector 3 that is passed on to the function comes from ray cast
using screenPointToRay

Comment: What do u mean by node?  is it a 2D project? or related to GUI?

Comment: The nodes are just a class with x and y data along with world positions and some other data

Comment: its working for Grid 0?

Comment: For world position x=0, z=0 it should return node at lower-left corner of grid 0 and for the position x = 2*gridSize ,z = 2*gridSize ,, it should return upper right node of grid 3.. Correct me if im wrong

Comment: @HassaanAkbar each node is a 2x2 so it would be 4*grid size, 

the large grids start at 0,0 grid 1 is at 0,100, 2 is at 100,0, and 3 is at 100,100

Comment: grids.ElementAt returns the larger grid? and gc[x, z] returns the snaller grid (node)? and `gridsize.x = gridsize.y = 2` and `LargeGridSize.x = LargeGridSizey = 100` right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right then this should work for u. It includes the lower boundary of the node and excludes upper boundary.. i.e if u give world point 2,0 then it will return 2nd node.

```
 public Node NodeFromWorldPoint(Vector3 worldPosition)
{

    //Gets the Large grid number 0-3
    int LargeX = (int)worldPosition.x / (2 * gridWorldSize.x);
    int LargeZ = (int)worldPosition.z / (2 * gridWorldSize.z);
    int tilenumber = LargeX*2 + LargeZ;

    //get the position of the smaller grid
    float percentX = worldPosition.x/gridWorldSize.x - LargeX;
    float percentZ = worldPosition.z/gridWorldSize.z - LargeZ;

    int x = (int)percentX/gridSizeX;
    int x = (int)percentZ/gridSizeZ;

    var gc = grids.ElementAt(tilenumber);
    return gc[x, z];
}
```